# Reset nested isDirty states with combineReducers in redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So in my store, I have multiple states per `fruitId` and each `fruitId` has a `isDirty` state. Then I have 2 actions, `RESET_DIRTY` with the `fruitId` and `RESET_ALL`. The follow code works. But I think I was wondering if there is a way to do this with `combineReducers` so that I can clean up this pattern ?

My store looks like this right now and I was wondering how

```
function fruits(state = {}, action) {
  return { 
    isDirty: isDirty(state.isDirty, action)
  }
}

function isDirty(state = false, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.RESET_DIRTY:
      return false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default function fruitStore(state = {}, action) {
  if (!action.type.startsWith('fruits')) {
    return state;
  }

  const { fruitId } = action;
  const { currentFruit } = fruitId ? { 
    [fruitId] : fruits(state[fruitId], action) 
  } : {};

  let newState = Object.assign({}, state, currentFruit);

  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.RESET_DIRTY_ALL:
      newState = Object.assign({}, newState);

      Object.keys(newState).forEach((key) => {
        newState[key].isDirty = false;
      });

      return newState;
    default:
      return newState;
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of really great patterns for cleaning up Redux, but using **Ducks** is by far my favorite of all of them. This repo on Github gives you a rundown of how to structure your files in this fashion:

[Github: Modular Redux Ducks](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux)

Comment: Interesting .. will check it out ...but the problem i am running into now is rif its possible to just  use combineReducer  to handle nested updated like isDirty state resrt . so i do can simple above